# onSortChanged not triggering

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

using ag-grid 21.0.1,

my onSortChanged handler is not triggering when the user changes the grid sort by clicking on the column header.

```
function sortHandler(sortEvent: SortChangedEvent) {
    sortEvent.api.refreshCells({
        columns: sortEvent.api.getSortModel().map((c: any) => c.colId)
    });
}
return (
    <AgGridReact
            headerHeight={headerHeight}
            rowData={data}
            gridOptions={gridOptions}
            pinnedBottomRowData={footerRow}
            pinnedTopRowData={headerRow}
            onSortChanged={sortHandler}
        />
```

doesn't matter if I pass sortHandler as a prop to the react component or I declare it on the gridOptions object

Comment: I assume you are using React TypeScript?

Comment: yes react typescript + ag-grid 21.0.1